# How to access cisco connection on Win7 from Mac OS X on local network

Tags: windows, macos, cisco

I've really benefitted from all the answers out here and now it's my turn to ask for help.

My company uses CISCO VPN.  They won't give me the Shared Secret for the group so I am forced to use the windows VM to connect to my work network.

I've tried using the MAC CISCO ISPEC but there it is.   Anyway, I'd like to use the connection in my windows vm from my MAC side.  I tried setting up a openVPN server on the windows and connecting to that from MAC and connect the CISCO vpn.  All a no go.

So any suggestions will be very welcome.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Well it might sound strange but you're going to have to setup 2 virtual NICs on the virtual machine. The first NIC is going to be bridged with the real physical NIC on the OSX box and that's going to be your outside interface. The next virtual NIC is going to be a host-only and this is going to be your inside interface. This is the one you'll use for OSX to connect through your windows machine. Then you'll need to remove all IP and DHCP configuration from your physical NIC on OSX to let the virtual machine use that NIC.

Every time you want to use the VM and the VPN you're going to have to remove the config on your physical NIC in OSX and then re-add it when you're done.

The windows machine will need to use internet connection sharing to allow OSX to use its VPN connection.

[image]